# Error request for member 'salario' in something not a structure or union

Tags: struct, float, dev-c++, soma

Galera, preciso de ajuda com a soma de variáveis de uma struct.
o programa não compila e apresenta esse erro [Error] request for member 'salario' in something not a structure or union. O objetivo é somar os valores inseridos pelo usuario no campo salario.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct funcionario
{
    char nome[40];
    float salario;
};

struct funcionario cad_func[2];
int main(void) {

    int i;

    printf("INSIRA SEUS DADOS.\n\n\n");

    for(i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        printf("nome: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(cad_func[i].nome);

        printf("salario: ");
        scanf("%f", &cad_func[i].salario);

        printf("\n\n");
    }

    system("cls");

    printf("------------SEGUE ABAIXO NOME E SALARIO------------\n\n");

    for(i=0; i<2; i++){
        printf("Nome: %s\n", cad_func[i].nome);
        printf("Salario: %f\n\n\n", cad_func[i].salario);
    }

    float totalSalario;

    totalSalario = cad_func.salario[0] + cad_func.salario[1];

    printf("Total: %f", totalSalario);

    return 0;
}
```

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perceba que ao efetuar o cálculo do `totalSalario` você tentar acessar o `salario` da estrutra `funcionario` como se fosse um *array*:

```
totalSalario = cad_func.salario[0] + cad_func.salario[1];
```

Porém na verdade a sua variável `cad_func` é um *array*, portanto o acesso a índices na verdade precisa ser feito na `cad_func` e não no `salario`:

```
totalSalario = cad_func[0].salario + cad_func[1].salario;
```